# Creating abstract patterns from string data in R

Tags: r

I am trying to find patterns in strings in R by assigning tokens to the locations. I have a vector of the following form. It is basically change of location by a person in one year. For example in first case One person is moving from London to New york to London to Beijing and to cleveland.

```
path <- c('Lon-NYC-Lon-Bei-Cle', 'Mos-NYC-Bei-Cle-San', 'Bei-Cle-Bei-NYC-San')
```

I am trying to look for generic abstract patterns. I want to create a variable called: 'pattern' which gives me A-B-A-C-D for Lon-NYC-Lon-Bei-Cle string, A-B-C-D-E for Mos-NYC-Bei-Cle-San, A-B-A-C-D for Bei-Cle-Bei-NYC-San.

```
pattern <- c('A-B-A-C-D', 'A-B-C-D-E', 'A-B-A-C-D)
```

Is there a way I can create this variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you always have fewer than 26 unique values, you can use something like this

```
sapply(strsplit(path,"-"), function(x) 
    paste(LETTERS[factor(x, levels=unique(x))], collapse="-")
)
# [1] "A-B-A-C-D" "A-B-C-D-E" "A-B-A-C-D"
```

here we use `strsplit()` to find the different pieces and `factor()` to take care of identifying duplicate values. Then we use the numeric values underlying the factor to index into the set of upper-case letters